# Fancy Box not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I recently started experimenting with fancy box. I am triggering the fancy box when there is a preg match in the url. Everything is running fine except upon clicking OK or CANCEL the 
fancy box is not closing.

```
if(preg_match('/school/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
    {
       ?>
       <script>$("#single_image").fancybox().trigger('click');</script>
       <?php

    } 

<div style="display:none;" id="single_image" >
<p>Continue or Decline</p>
<p><input type="button" onclick="php_function();" value="OK" /><input type="button" value="CANCEL" onclick="$.fancybox.close();"</p></div>
```

php_function() is a javascript function for ajax call.

Comment: Does it return any error in javascript console?

Comment: no error in the console.

Comment: does the closing thing got anything to do with fancybox().trigger('click');

Comment: you have a typo, your cancel `input` with the  `onclick` is not properly closed.

Comment: thanks. I rectified it but still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

why not open it whith its method instead trigger('click') ?

```
$.fancybox.open( [group], [options] )
```

ref: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: does the closing thing got anything to do with fancybox().trigger('click');?